# SQL Schema - single products / product variations and stock levels

Tags: sql, database-design, schema, e-commerce, database-schema

I am creating an inventory management system and have come up against a bit of an obstacle.

A product can have no variations or have multiple:

Product 1: A pair of cufflinks (no variations)
Product 2: A shirt (white / Small, White / Medium etc)

I have followed the usual pattern of separating out the product variations into a seperate table.

The problem comes when I try to manage stock for these items.

I calculate stock on the fly by running a query against goods received and goods ordered.

What is the best way to deal with products that do not have a variation?

Should I create a blank variation for a product and use that to calculate the stock on hand or should I alter the query to search both the product table and the variations table?

I hope I haven't made a pigs ear of the explanation!  Hopefully someone can piece together what I am referring to.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Blank variations (and requiring at least one variation per product) will make for the simplest and most consistent schema and queries. If most of your products have no variations, there is the downside of managing lots of relatively pointless blank ones, but I'm assuming that's not the case.

And even though the cufflinks only come in one style, they probably have a colour, and you can call the size "one-size". Similar observations may apply to other products and variation attributes.